# How to fix jQuery error that stops DIVI edit screen DIVI Editor working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, divi

Apologies in advance... this is a first post here.

I have a website I've inherited that uses a custom booking widget code.

The code causing the issue changes the CSS class based on a screen size and a scroll position
(if the window width is above 960 and the scroll position is below 300).

It does achieve the above but causes a conflict with the DIVI builder edit screen that prevents it from loading...I just cant figure out how to update this.

I believe the issue is in the script tags being included in the header (or body) in this way and it is messing with the Wordpress and DIVI jQuery process. Divi uses wordpress jquery as i understand it.

**The current code is:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/Javascript"><!--

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        let widget_scrolled = false;
        let scroll_level = 300;

        if ($(window).width() > 960) {

            $(window).scroll(function() {
                var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                var new_scroll = scroll >= scroll_level;
                if(widget_scrolled !== new_scroll){
                    $("#c5QuickBook").toggleClass("uk-widget-scrolled");
                }
                widget_scrolled = new_scroll;
            });
        } else {
            $("#c5QuickBook").addClass("uk-widget-scrolled");
        }
    });
```

An alternative initial script tag works (as below) but this also breaks the DIVI editor.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(removed link to dev site as it is private)

Thanks in advance.
Chris

Comment: Why are you loading your own jQuery version? This isn't recommended and there's a good article on why you SHOULD NOT change the jQuery version that WordPress uses here: https://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/

Comment: You would also only need to change the first line of your code from $( document ).ready(function() to jQuery( document ).ready(function($)

Answer (score 0):

`$` is not available with jQuery in Wordpress.

If you want to work with `$`, you should wrap your code with the following:

```
($ => {
    // Your code here
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated and have a working system and no errors onconsole or the edit screen..  Thanks so much. I was trying to post the code as it now looks into comments but it wasnt formatting... i'll add it as an answer and if i've still messed it up maybe you. someone else can comment on that.

Comment: @chrisdavisberry Great! glad I could help. You don't need to post your working code as an answer. If you think it will benefit others than sure, add it. In my opinion you can remove your answer, as it doesn't seem like something general that others can use. its up to you.

Comment: Thanks again. Your comment is the answer really so i'll leave it like that. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Good article on why you SHOULD NOT change the jQuery version that WordPress uses here: https://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/